# How to use AuthorizationServer in a SystemTest to create JWT tokens without Authentication

Tags: spring, jwt, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I have a SystemTest. This means, i start all my Applications and access them only by doing REST calls. I also create for every Test a new User.

Now i have to add Security to my Application. This will be "OpenId Connect". Currently nothing is implemented. As there are many Tutorials, i thinks the implementation will be "easy". But I am not sure how to handle my SystemTest.

I think one solution could be using the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/releases/tag/0.2.0. See also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server#authServerImplementation

My resource server will have only this configuration

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
```

I think my test should work like this:

1. create a User with a Rest call that is not secured (technical API). The user will be saved in the database
2. call the Authorization Server with the User Details i know from 1). This will give me a JWT token.
3. call the REST API like a Client would do. Add in the Header the JWT token.
4. This happen automaticity handled by Spring: the Resource Server calls the Authorization Server to get the Certificate (see issuer-uri) and validates the JWT.

Question:

1. Do you know a better solution for my SystemTest
2. Do you have any Idea how to implement 2)

Update: Another Idea:
Maybe it would be good to use a slim OpenId Connect Client in the SystemTest. Then i have to modify only the Authorization Server to register user dynamic. I also have to ensure that user need no credentials, he must be just allowed to to things.

Best regards
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my Problem :-) I created an App that has this Controller and other Classes.
I hope it help the other dev :-)

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/openid-connect/mock")
public class OpenIdConnectMockController {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    private KeyPair rsaKeyPair;
    private RSAKey jwkRsaPublicKey;

    @PostConstruct
    public void generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, JOSEException {
        this.rsaKeyPair = generateRsaKeyPair(2048);
        logger.info("generate key {}", this.rsaKeyPair.getPublic());
        RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) this.rsaKeyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) this.rsaKeyPair.getPrivate();
        this.jwkRsaPublicKey = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaPublicKey).build();
        logger.info("jwkRsaPublicKey (JWK-Format) {}", this.jwkRsaPublicKey);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/keys", produces = "application/json")
    public String keys() {
        logger.info("Keys was called {}", this.jwkRsaPublicKey.toString());
        return "{\"keys\":[" + this.jwkRsaPublicKey.toString() + "]}";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/private-key", produces = "application/json")
    public byte[] getPrivateKey() throws JOSEException {
        RSAKey privateKey = new RSAKey.Builder((RSAPublicKey) this.rsaKeyPair.getPublic()).privateKey(this.rsaKeyPair.getPrivate()).build();
        return privateKey.toRSAPrivateKey().getEncoded();
    }

    private KeyPair generateRsaKeyPair(int keyLengthInt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keypairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keypairGenerator.initialize(keyLengthInt, new SecureRandom());
        return keypairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }

}
```

```
 public static Jwt jwtTokenClient(String userId) {
        byte[] privateKey = OpenIdConnectMockService.privateKey(openIdConnectMockWebClient);
        return JwtUtil.createJWT(privateKey, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "MS-SystemTest-Issuer", userId);
    }
```

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Date;

public class JwtUtil {

    public static final long SECOND_IN_MILLIS = 1000;
    public static final long MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 60;
    public static final long HOUR_IN_MILLIS = MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 60;
    public static final long DAY_IN_MILLIS = HOUR_IN_MILLIS * 24;

    private JwtUtil() {
    }

    public static Jwt createJWT(byte[] privateKey, String id, String issuer, String subject) {
        //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.RS256;

        long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //We will sign our JWT with our ApiKey secret
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey);
        KeyFactory rsaFact = null;
        try {
            rsaFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey) rsaFact.generatePrivate(spec);

            JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId(id)
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date(nowMillis))
                    .setSubject(subject)
                    .setIssuer(issuer)
                    .setExpiration(new Date(nowMillis + DAY_IN_MILLIS))
                    .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, key);

            //Builds the JWT and serializes it to a compact, URL-safe string
            return new Jwt(builder.compact());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```